# Copy & paste automatic in a same gdoc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Inside a google doc document, I regularly have to copy-paste whole paragraphs in various places.

Is there a way to copy my paragraph so that it replicates at places defined in the google doc?

With the macros function on google sheet, I can do it very well but I need to work in a doc environment.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. You migth find helpful to start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can use the [`replaceText()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) method of the `Body` class to replace text in a document programmatically.*

#### Code:

```js
function replaceText(){
  const pText = "This is a long paragraph that I have to insert into my\
  document a load of times so instead of copying and pasting it each\
  time I need to use it, I will simply use the built-in replaceText()\
  method - it will replace all instances of the string {{paragraph}}.";

  var docBody = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  docBody.replaceText('{{paragraph}}', pText); 
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Text | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text)
- [Class Body | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)